# Choose some items in a dataframe and change them

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with some information. Some data is NA. Something like:

```
    id fact sex
1   1    3    M
2   2    6    F
3   3    NA  <NA>
4   4    8    F
5   5    2    F
6   6    2    M
7   7    NA  <NA>
8   8    1    F
9   9   10    M
10 10   10    M
```

I have to change fact by some rule(e.x. multiply by 3 elements, that have (data == "M")).

I tried `survey$fact[survey$sex== "M"] <- survey$fact[survey$sex== "M"] * 3`, but I have some error because of NA.

I know I can check if element is NA with is.na(x), and add this condition in [...], but I hope that exists more beautiful solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like `ifelse`, it always seems to have the desired behaviour with respect to `NA` values for me.

`survey$fact <- ifelse(survey$sex == "M", survey$fact * 3, survey$fact)`

`?ifelse` shows that the first argument is the test, the second the value assigned if the test is `true` and the final argument the value if `false`.  If you assign the original `data.frame` column as the `false` return value, it will assign rows for which the test fails without modifying them.

This is an extension of what you asked, to show that you can also test for `NA` values.

`survey$fact <- ifelse(is.na(survey$sex), survey$fact * 2, survey$fact)`

I also like that it's very readable.

Answer (score 1):

`which` can filter those `NA`s:

```
survey$fact[which(survey$sex == "M")] <- survey$fact[which(survey$sex== "M")] * 3
```

There are many ways you can make that a little cleaner, e.g.:

```
males <- which(survey$sex == "M")
survey$fact[males] <- 3 * survey$fact[males]
```

or

```
survey <- within(survey, fact[males] <- 3 * fact[males])
```